# i want inject producer into service

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-kafka, spring-data-jpa

i want inject producer for kafka into service but i have issues
and without inject producer i dont have any error in my code

**this is my issuse when run my code :**

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/home/abed/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

**and then close connection with data base with this exception** No operations allowed after connection closed.

**with this**

```
2021-04-23 01:16:17.331[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36masc.foods.store.config.WebConfigurer    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Web application configuration, using profiles: swagger
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.331[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36masc.foods.store.config.WebConfigurer    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Web application fully configured
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.941[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.AscStore.stories [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.941[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.AppUser      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.941[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.Driver       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.941[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.Branch.orders    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.942[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.Rating       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.942[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.AppUser.orders   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.942[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.s.d.AppUser.userAddresses     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.942[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.User         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.942[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.Product      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.942[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.OrderProduct [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.942[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.s.domain.UserAddress.orders   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.943[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.Driver.orders    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.943[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.s.domain.OrderStatusHistory   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.943[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.AppUser.ratings  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.943[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.User.authorities [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.943[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.StoreFollower    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.943[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.ProductOption    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.944[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.Product.orders   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.944[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.s.d.Product.productOptions    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.944[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.AppUser.friends  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.944[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.s.domain.AppUser.friendOfs    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.944[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.s.domain.AscOrder.products    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.944[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.AscOrder.ratings [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.944[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.Driver.ratings   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.945[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.Branch       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.945[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.s.domain.AscStore.promoCodes  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.945[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.s.domain.FoodGenre.products   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.945[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.FoodGenre.stores [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.945[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.UserAddress  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.945[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.FoodGenre    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.946[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.Authority    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.946[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.PromoCode    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.946[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.s.domain.AscStore.products    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.946[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.s.domain.AscStore.foodGeners  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.946[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.AscOrder     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.946[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.store.domain.AppUser.follows  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.946[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.Story        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.946[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.s.domain.AscStore.branches    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.947[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.foods.store.domain.AscStore     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.947[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.c.E.f.s.domain.AscStore.followedBys [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.948[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByEmail     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.948[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByLogin     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.948[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.e.core.Ehcache-oAuth2Authentication   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Close successful.
[2m2021-04-23 01:16:17.962[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m26002[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[-service-task-1][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Hikari - Connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@49dd7753 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:1857)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:396)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:336)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.rollback(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1161)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:251)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:213)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:184)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:366)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.java:46)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:118)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:93)
    at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

lock at my service and my producer

this producer

```
    @Component

public class BranchProducer {

    private static final String TOPIC = "updateRate";
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BranchService.class);
    private static final String groupId = "store-service";

    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    private final BranchService branchService;

    public BranchProducer(BranchService branchService, KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.branchService = branchService;
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    public void produceUpdateRate(Map<String, String> rate) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {

            kafkaTemplate.send("updateRate", mapper.writeValueAsString(rate));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

and this service in my servies just inject BranchProducer
but when inject i am showing this error
i dont what happened

```
@Service
@Transactional

public class BranchService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BranchService.class);

    private final BranchRepository branchRepository;

    private final BranchMapper branchMapper;

    private final AscStoreRepository ascStoreRepository;

    private final AscStoreMapper ascStoreMapper;

    private final AscOrderMapper ascOrderMapper;

    private final AscOrderRepository ascOrderRepository;

    private final AscStoreService ascStoreService;
    
    private final BranchProducer branchProducer; //when delete this no have this issues 
    

    public BranchService(BranchRepository branchRepository, AscOrderMapper ascOrderMapper, BranchMapper branchMapper,
            AscStoreRepository ascStoreRepository, AscStoreMapper ascStoreMapper, AscOrderRepository ascOrderRepository,
            AscStoreService ascStoreService,BranchProducer branchProducer //when delete this no have this issues) {
        this.branchRepository = branchRepository;
        this.branchMapper = branchMapper;
        this.ascStoreMapper = ascStoreMapper;
        this.ascStoreRepository = ascStoreRepository;
        this.ascOrderMapper = ascOrderMapper;
        this.ascOrderRepository = ascOrderRepository;
        this.ascStoreService = ascStoreService;
        this.branchProducer=branchProducer; //when delete this no have this issues
    }
```

Comment: You have circular dependency that is sure to cause a problem: your producer constructor takes a service, and the service takes a producer.  You need to break the cycle.

Comment: how can i break the cycle? @duffymo

Comment: The producer should not depend on the service.  Remove the service from its dependencies.  Rewrite the producer until that works.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in producer contractor
producer cant find BranchService
the solve problem  just delete `branchService` from **constructor**